# Code Igniter not displaying my data (but no error shown)

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

EDIT : Does not work on external hosting AND on localhost… So I must be doing something wrong.

I am working with Code Igniter and I have a view. My view page shows no error, but doesn't show the data I requested either.   Everythings fine with my config and database I guess... 
Any idea ? Am I doing anything wrong here?
I am using latest version of mamp on mac 4.4.1 and latest version of code igniter 3.1.7.

Thanks guys in advance for your help ;)

View

```
    <?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
?><!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <body>
<div>

         <p> <?php

        echo 'Trying to display:' . $data . ' yes?';

        ?> </p>


    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Model

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Welcome_model extends CI_Model {

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function get_secret($id)
    { 
            $this->db->where('id', $id);
            $this->db->select('secret');
            $query = $this->db->get('tch_api');

            if ($query->num_rows==1) {
                foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
//  tried with this line too : $secret = $row->secret; and without the following one same result 
                    $data[] = $row->secret;
                }
                return $data;
            }

    }
}
```

Controller

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Welcome extends CI_Controller {

    public function index()
    {

        $this->load->model('welcome_model');

        $secret = $this->welcome_model->get_secret(1);
        $data = array(
            'data' => $secret
        );
        $this->load->view('welcome_message', $data);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try with `isset`?
Please change the view like:

```
    <?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
?><!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <body>
<div>

         <p> <?php
              if (isset($data))
               { echo 'Trying to display:' . $data . ' yes?';} else { echo 'No data found' ;} ?> </p>


    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**UPDATE**

Assuming from your above code that you want to get the data of Id 1 from table and show it in your view.

Please do the following changes and try again.

**Model**

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Welcome_model extends CI_Model {

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function get_secret($id)
    { 
            $this->db->where('id', $id);
            $this->db->select('secret');
            $query = $this->db->get('tch_api');
         return $query->result();

    }
}
```

?>

**Controller**

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Welcome extends CI_Controller {

public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('welcome_model','wl');
    }


    public function index()
    {

        $data['secret'] = $this->wl->get_secret(1);
        $this->load->view('welcome_message', $data);

    }
}
?>
```

**View**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Data Fetching</title>
</head>
    <body>
<div>

         <p><?php
         //testing 1
         if(isset($data)){var_dump($data);}

         //testing 2
              if (isset($data))
               { echo 'Trying to display:' . $data . ' yes?';} else { echo 'No data found' ;} ?> </p>


    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Please try this and post your result here..

Please mark it as Answer if the issue has been Fixed.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It now echos : "Trying to display: yes?' Even if I change the id to 2 in the model (and there is no row with id 2)

Comment: okay, try this first:
`if(isset($data)){var_dump($data);}` and you will see what is coming in that data variable.

Comment: That returns : string(0) ""   But there is really data with id 1 in my database and table tch_api... So its not normal at all... I tried with other database, and on external FTP as on localhost, exactly same issue.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help mate.  I guess you were a little tired, because in the view now it needs to be tested if isset  $secret, and not if isset $data.   So I did what you told me and tried with isset $secret, and now I have a different output : array(1) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#19 (1) { ["secret"]=> string(30) "5v9ryiMJXR3ZajkoUdDIUFH0R2fQq8" } }
This is for the var_dump. But when I try to ECHO it, I get an error :  Array to string conversion
Also, you put "?>" at the end of the controller and the model, but I never did that previously, I guess you were tired and added it by mistake.

Comment: I had to use print_r for printing the variable ;) Thanks man thanks to both of you and Parth Gundania now its fully working ;)

Answer (score 0):

You are doing a few strange things. Firstly in your `get_secret` function you only expect one row, hence one value for secret judging by your logic; you should thus use `row()` not `result()`. Further, I expect your issue is that (1) your function doesn't return anything when the item with `$id` doesn't exist in database and (2) you are trying to echo an array (which will result in an array to string conversion). Assuming you just want to get the value of `secret` where `$id = 1` you should do the following:

```
function get_secret($id)
{ 
        $this->db->where('id', $id);
        $this->db->select('secret');
        $query = $this->db->get('tch_api');

        if ($query->num_rows==1) {
            return $query->row()->secret;
        } else {
            return '';
        }

}
```

The rest of your code should work. If you still don't see any results, verify that a row with `$id = 1` exists as that can be the only other issue.

Comment: Hello, thanks I changed it like you. Its clearer now. But there is still no result, even if a row exists with id 1. I do not understand... I tried to create another database, change the config, and the problem is the same with another database and other table, i'm lost. I have a website on FTP that works with this model controller and view. I have MAMP on mac, perhaps  I failed to config the code igniter ? What do I have to config exactly ? I configured the database.php, and autoload.php (libraries database).

Answer (score 0):

controller:

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Welcome extends CI_Controller {

    public function index()
    {

        $this->load->model('welcome_model'); 
        $data['data'] = $this->welcome_model->get_secret(1);
        $this->load->view('welcome_message', $data);

    }
}
```

model:

```
function get_secret($id)
{ 
        $this->db->where('id', $id);
        $this->db->select('secret');
        $query = $this->db->get('tch_api'); 
        if ($query->num_rows==1) 
        {
             return $query->row->secret;
         }
         else
         {
             return "";
        }

}
```

and simply display in view

```
   <?php echo $data;?>
```

Comment: Hello, thanks I changed it like you. Its clearer now. But there is still no result, even if a row exists with id 1. I do not understand... I tried to create another database, change the config, and the problem is the same with another database and other table, i'm lost. I have a website on FTP that works with this model controller and view. I have MAMP on mac, perhaps  I failed to config the code igniter ? What do I have to config exactly ? I configured the database.php, and autoload.php (libraries database).

Comment: glad to hear that. if it helped please mark it as answer.am not familiar with mac julien am sorry..

Comment: echo $this->db->last_query();exit();   put this after   $query = $this->db->get('tch_api'); in model this it will show you the query- run that query and check if there is any data

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply bro. It did not help unfortunately my friend so I cannot mark it as answer… The line echo $this->db->last_query();exit() works it just echos the db_request.

Answer (score 0):

$data in view will be an array
And echo can not print an array, try using print_r

view

```
<?php
    defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <p>
             <?php
                echo 'Trying to display:';
                print_r($data);

             ?>
             </p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, print_r works fine with the second error I had ;)

Comment: As $data is an array, You can use echo $data[0] too.